Producing 3-way Interaction Tables
my negative binomial final model has 2,significant 3-way interactions. Here's the code I've used for the nb.
Final_model_acetotal_demo_17_20 <-  glm.nb(acetotal ~ (group + fed_pov_level + gender +                   race_eth + metro)^2 
            + group:race_eth:metro
            + group:race_eth:fed_pov_level, 
            data=NSCH2_2017_2020)

The table in the console is horrendous to look at and I've tried to get different tables to populate in viewer or as a html to no avail. I've tried
tbl_regression(Final_model_acetotal_demo_17_20, exponentiate = T, intercept = T) 

won't run, just stays in process forever
tab_model(Final_model_acetotal_demo_17_20, ci_method="wald")

warning that says "Profiled confidence intervals may take longer time to compute.
Use ci_method="wald" for faster computation of CIs.
Model matrix is rank deficient. Parameters groupDHH:race_ethOther:metroYes were
not estimable."
Then keeps trying to run and nothing happens.
texreg::knitreg(list(ROI_null_re, fit_ROI3, fit_ROI4, fit_ROI5, fit_ROI6),
            caption = "MLM: Response Time", caption.above = TRUE,
            label = "table:nulls",
            float.pos = "hb",
            bold = .05)

this does run but produces a minimally better version of the results in the console.
Any ideas of how to get a better looking table are welcomed! Thanks!!

I'm afraid you'll need to add additional tags, that is not HTML.

Welcome to [so]. as written, your question is too broad. Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically are not a good fit for this site.  Split your task into smaller ones and start working on them. And ask particular questions related to particular issues you encounter. Here's how: how-to-ask
